# compile c++ through shell with jenkins

Tags: c++, jenkins

I'm trying to make a jenkinsfile to compile c++ file through the shell however i'm having the following error:

1.scripts/Linux-Build.sh: 5: cmake: not found

2. scripts/Linux-Build.sh: 5: make: not found

my jenkinsfile:

```
    pipeline {    
          agent any  
         /*  environment {
           PATH = "${env.PATH}:/usr/bin"    }
        */ stages{
             stage('Build'){
                steps{
                 echo "Building..."
                 echo "PATH is: ${env.PATH}"
                 sh 'chmod +x scripts/Linux-Build.sh'
                 sh 'scripts/Linux-Build.sh'
          }    }    stage('Test'){
            steps{
                sh 'echo "Running..."'
                sh 'chmod +x scripts/Linux-Run.sh'
                sh 'scripts/Linux-Run.sh'
           }    
  }
}
```

Linux-Build.sh:
#!/bin/sh

echo "${PATH}"

cmake .
make

jenkins console output:

```
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f eba9957b24cf36c5d5666036e45669ea04bea366 # timeout=10
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D master # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b master eba9957b24cf36c5d5666036e45669ea04bea366 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Update"
 > git rev-list --no-walk c712362f967199fdd279560bad38e3f26e3a5759 # timeout=10
Cleaning workspace
 > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
Resetting working tree
 > git reset --hard # timeout=10
 > git clean -fdx # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] echo
Building...
[Pipeline] echo
PATH is: /opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[Pipeline] sh
+ chmod +x scripts/Linux-Build.sh
[Pipeline] sh
+ scripts/Linux-Build.sh
/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
scripts/Linux-Build.sh: 6: cmake: not found
scripts/Linux-Build.sh: 7: make: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
Stage "Test" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Does your build agent have cmake and make installed?

Comment: I had similar issues compiling on a Raspberry.  I had code that would compile on windows but not in linux.  Found the paths weren't being passed the same in linux and windows.  In linux the make file had to be in the parent folder of the source files.  In windows you could pass an path do the make utility and it would work.

Comment: Yes the cmake and make are installed.

Comment: Can you please give us the result of `which cmake` and the path info that is logged by your `Linux-Build.sh`?

Comment: which cmake = /usr/bin/cmake

Comment: Path = /usr/bin:/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:usr/sbin:/usr:/sbin:/bin

Comment: Is this the path of your current working shell or the path echoed by your Linux-Build.sh?

Comment: the path echoed by Linux-Buiild.sh

Comment: Hmm ... can you please add the `which cmake` as a new line after the `echo "${PATH}"` and test again? Then please copy the exact script and its output as separate code sections to your question.

Comment: I added the which cmake, but in jenkins console output is not printing his result.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1. As Stephen said, log in to the server where the pipeline actually is executed and check with `which cmake` and `which make` if the tools are installed on that machine. It is very unlikely that they are. If you are not sure on which server the pipeline is executed you can add the command `hostname` to your shell-script to dump it.
2. After cmake is installed and can be found, please double-check the last line of your script. In the question it is `cmake . make`. This looks odd to me. I would expect some configure and/or build step [link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/A%20Basic%20Starting%20Point.html#build-and-run).
3. Finally, you may want to use the [CMake plugin for Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/cmakebuilder/) instead of a batch script.