# jenkins running unit test of c++ code from visual studio on

Tags: c++, visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration

first of all I will show you how the program is structured:

[image]

I built the solution using jenkins as shown in the figure below
[image]

this is a cpp program. I do not know how to run unit test since there is no .exe file for unit test.

here is the .obj and .dll files in unit test folder
[image]

I know I should use MSbuild but I cannot find any thing that tells me how to run unittest on jenkins

Comment: Is your jenkins installed on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

### Gold Rule #1 in devops

The steps should work in your localhost preferable on Linux and **using the shell**, before port it to Jenkins. If it don't work even on your localhost, Jenkins can't do anything.

Then if it works in your localhost (all the shells and installed tools required) , in jenkins you could use on of these approaches:

1. Jenkins shell script
2. Some Jenkins plugin to avoid the shell or scripts

### Gold Rule #2 in devops

Use the shell, not programs with user interface , sometimes called IDEs. Devops flows for build, test, deploy **are executed in the background and the 99.999% on Linux**, not windows

### c++ build

Reviewing, **cmkake** is used to build c++ applications. Also some others tools:

- g++
- make
- cc
- gcc

More details here: [How to compile a c++ program in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005713/how-to-compile-a-c-program-in-linux)

Here a sample with **g++**

```
# compile
g++ ./foo/bar.cpp -o ./foo/bar
# this will generate an executable file ./foo/bar ready to be used
```

Since you have several files, you only need to append the files to the g++ according to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30064940/3957754

### unit test

Depending of the classification (compiled/interpreted), execute a unit test is just to run a file:

**java**

- mvn clean test

Searches all *Test.java files and if the files has the @Test annotation, the file is executed

**nodejs**

- node /foo/bar/test.js
- jest ...
- mocha  'src/test/**/*.test.js'

Similar to java but with *.test.js files

As you can see, unit test **is just to execute a file** some times compiled previously or directly execution. So in your case, since c++ is a **compiled** language, to run your test , you only need

```
# compile
g++ ./UnitTest/UnitTest.cpp -o ./UnitTest/UnitTest

# run
./UnitTest/UnitTest
```

### Visual Studio

This tool is for c#. If you read the previous paragraphs, you don't need complicated tools to build c++ projects.

### Windows

You only  need to choose one tool, install it on your windows, open the CMD shell or powershell and try the commands

- g++
- make
- cc
- gcc

If it works, go to your jenkins and use the shell step

### References

- https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/app-development/cpp/linux/
- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-compile-and-run-c-cplusplus-code-in-linux/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/61408/what-is-a-command-to-compile-and-run-c-programs
- [compile c++ through shell with jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71914442/compile-c-through-shell-with-jenkins)
- https://thoughts-on-coding.com/2019/03/27/introduction-into-build-automation-setup-with-jenkins-and-cmake/
- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-compile-and-run-c-cplusplus-code-in-linux/
- [How to compile a c++ program in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005713/how-to-compile-a-c-program-in-linux)
- [Making and compiling C++ projects with multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064686/making-and-compiling-c-projects-with-multiple-files)
- https://www.baeldung.com/cs/compiled-vs-interpreted-languages